# ldap_search_ext returns extra result

Tags: c, ldap, openldap

I have some c code that queries an openldap server for a user DN based on the user cn as shown below. When I search the ldap server using Apache DS, there is only result that is shown. My C code however returns 2 records; one with the DN of the user as expected, and a second record with a blank DN!! What is this second record for? Is this expected behavior?

I have include the code sample below with all error checking removed for the sake of clarity.

```
ldap_search_ext(ld, (char *)baseDN, LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(&(objectClass=person)(cn=test00002))", NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, LDAP_NO_LIMIT, &msgid);
ldap_result(ld, msgid, 1, NULL, &res);
numUsersFound = ldap_count_messages(ld, res);
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "DEBUG Number of users found: (%d)", numUsersFound);
```

Result

```
DEBUG Number of users found: 2
DEBUG User DN: (cn=test00002,ou=defaultRealm,dc=company,dc=com)
DEBUG User DN: ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Did some more troubleshooting and I found out there are 2 methods:

```
> int ldap_count_entries( LDAP *ld, LDAPMessage *result );  => returns 1
> int ldap_count_messages( LDAP *ld, LDAPMessage *result ); => returns 2
```

Now, I am not entirely sure what the difference is between 'entry' and 'message', but atleast it solves the mystery partially.

Answer (score 0):

`ldap_count_entries` and its related routines (`ldap_first_entry` and `ldap_next_entry`) only return entries, that is, the results of your search.

`ldap_count_messages` (and `ldap_first_message`, `ldap_next_message`) also include search references, i.e. references to other servers or naming contexts.

[Source](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/directory/csdk-docs/search.htm#c6-overview-searching-with-ldap-api-functions).  I've found the old Mozilla LDAP documentation quite useful for explaining LDAP concepts.